# Pygrass reading raster issue

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script, grass-7.0

I'm tring to read a raster map from my grassData.

I'm using this code

```
import os
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
from grass.pygrass import raster

gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']  
gisdbase = os.path.abspath("/home/myuser/grassData") 
location = 'mylocation'           
mapset = 'mymapset' 
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdbase, location, mapset)

elev=raster.RasterRow('elevation')
elev.open()
for row in elev:
    print row
```

But I get all values with nan, where is the error?

If I do `elev.info()` I get this result

```
elevation@
rows: 4502
cols: 5554
north: 45.0743663458 south: 45.0500262069 nsres:5.40651685671e-06
east:  7.67457811722 west: 7.6445503225 ewres:5.40651687473e-06
range: 233.050003052, 310.049987793
proj: 3
```

Tnx

Lorenzo

Answer (score 4):

The raster

[image]

If your raster is not in a the current region, all the values are `nan`

Therefore by security

```py
from grass.pygrass.gis.region import Region
current = Region()
current.align('aspect')
```

Then

```py
elev=raster.RasterRow('aspect') # one of my raster layers
elev.open()
elev.is_open()
True
elev.get_row(1)
Buffer([ nan,  nan,  nan, ...,  nan,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32)
elev.get_row(56)
Buffer([ nan,  296.56192017,  281.30841064, ...,  354.0930481 ,
    351.86880493, nan], dtype=float32)
# or
for row in elev[:3]:
   row[:4]
Buffer([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32)
Buffer([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32)
Buffer([nan,  45.00392151,  71.5674057 ,  59.03970337], dtype=float32)
# and
for row in elev:
    print row
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  45.00392151  71.5674057  ...,  63.43808365  45.00392151 nan]
 [ nan  63.43808365  90. ...,  59.03970337  59.03970337 nan]
 ....
 elev.cats[56]
 ('304 degrees ccw from east', 303.5, 304.5)
 from grass.pygrass.vector.geometry import Point
 elev.get_value(Point(237952.69,122535.2))
 160.63855
```